# Handling "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type"

Tags: typescript

Following code:

```
type ConfigValue = {
    title: string;
}

const enum ConfigKey {
    ConfigA = 'config-a',
    ConfigB = 'config-b'
}

// For each ConfigKey there must exist a record so I can't type it as Record<string, ConfigValue>. Doing config[ConfigKey.ConfigA] should be a safe action.
const config: Record<ConfigKey, ConfigValue> = {
    [ConfigKey.ConfigA]: {
        title: 'Config a title'
    },
    [ConfigKey.ConfigB]: {
        title: 'Config b title'
    }
};

// MaybeConfigKey value comes from some API so it's not always ConfigKey
function getConfigTitleOrFallback(maybeConfigKey: string) {

    // config[maybeConfigKey] throws this error.
    const configForKey = config[maybeConfigKey];

    if (configForKey) {
        return configForKey.title;
    }

    return 'Fallback value';
}

const title = config[ConfigKey.ConfigA].title;

console.log(title);
```

Produces the error in title. I found a way to solve it by either

a) Setting config type to:

```
Record<string, ConfigValue>
```

This doesn't work well for me since then it doesn't check that all config keys exist for sure and in other places of code I'm using config[ConfigKey.ConfigA]. This should be safe and always return with title.

b) It's also possible to use { suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors: true }, but I don't want to do that, because it doesn't seem like a good practice.

Is it possible to solve/approach this problem in some other, better way?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
const isConfigKey = (value: string): value is ConfigKey => {
  // For brevity
  return value === ConfigKey.ConfigA || value === ConfigKey.ConfigB;
}
```

And then use it in your `getConfigTitleOrFallback` function:

```
function getConfigTitleOrFallback(maybeConfigKey: string) {
  if (!isConfigKey(maybeConfigKey)) {
    return 'Fallback value';
  }

  // Something like
  return config[maybeConfigKey].title;
}
```

Another way would be to use `ts-type-checked`, a TypeScript transformer that can generate these type guards for you.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library :)

Comment: Thanks. This worked, I used return configKey in config.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the key to not always be of type `ConfigKey` you will need to tell typescript that it can also be a string

For Example

```
  type ConfigValue = {
    title: string;
}

const enum ConfigKey {
    ConfigA = 'config-a',
    ConfigB = 'config-b'
}

// For each ConfigKey there must exist a record so I can't type it as Record<string, ConfigValue>. Doing config[ConfigKey.ConfigA] should be a safe action.
const config: Record<ConfigKey | string, ConfigValue> = {
    [ConfigKey.ConfigA]: {
        title: 'Config a title'
    },
    [ConfigKey.ConfigB]: {
        title: 'Config b title'
    }
};

// MaybeConfigKey value comes from some API so it's not always ConfigKey
function getConfigTitleOrFallback(maybeConfigKey: ConfigKey | string) {

    // config[maybeConfigKey] throws this error.
    const configForKey = config[maybeConfigKey];

    if (configForKey) {
        return configForKey.title;
    }

    return 'Fallback value';
}

const title = config[ConfigKey.ConfigA].title;

console.log(title);
```

If you don't care you can also just cast the key to `ConfigKey`, since you're already returning a fall back value in case of a non-existing key, you should be safe:

```
function getConfigTitleOrFallback(maybeConfigKey: string) {

        // config[maybeConfigKey] throws this error.
        const configForKey = config[maybeConfigKey as ConfigKey];

        if (configForKey) {
            return configForKey.title;
        }

        return 'Fallback value';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not perfect though because if I do ```const title = config['non existant key'].title;```
somewhere in the code it doesn't throw an error. The answer with typeguard worked.

Edit: It also doesn't seem to enforce all ConfigKey to exist in the config.

Comment: @HenriErilaid if you do this and you are not sure whether or not the key from the api is valid, this will always throw an error. You will need to check if the key exists, or be sure that your api only returns valid keys.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are on the same page right now - I submitted my reply accidentally by pressing enter before, so maybe you saw wrong text. I meant that I do want it to throw an error, but if I used ConfigKey | string, it allowed me to write anything as a key and it also didn't throw an error when for example only one of the keys was actually configured.

Comment: Throw a compile error? If you're getting a key from an API you cannot be sure what it is going to be yet. Your solution works fine, it will return a fallback value if the function is handed an invalid key, no need for any 'type guards'. All you need to do is to tell typescript that you know what you're doing, because you can't just use a different type as an index.

Comment: Yeah, it should throw a compile error for it to be perfect in the following cases:
1. If a developer uses variable string anywhere else in the code to access config without checking first.
2. If developer adds a new ConfigKey enum value TypeScript should throw a compile error if this key doesn't exist within the config.

Right now I could also remove the check in the getConfigTitleOrFallback function and it seems to not throw an error.